# Subset data frame in batches of 100 rows

Tags: r, recursion, subset, lapply

I want to subset a large data frame by groups of 100 rows, to feed into a function.

A simplified example: Here's my "large" data frame of 1000 rows.

```
df<-data.frame(c(sample(2:100,1000,replace=TRUE)),c(sample(2:100,1000,replace=TRUE)))
```

I need to feed each group of 100 rows from df[,1] into this dummy function:

```
dummy<-function(x){
return(c("There are ",x," dummies in this room"))
}
```

I need to do this in sets of 100 because the dummy function can only handle 100 values at once.

This will feed the entirety of df[,1] into the function:

```
lapply(df[,1],dummy)
```

But instead, I need something like this:

```
lapply(df[1:100,1],dummy)
lapply(df[101:200,1]dummy)
. . . etc
```

How do I do this in a succinct way, preferably with base r?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont have a factor variable in your data set use `split` on or you dont want to go the vector route of `cut`, a short program like this might suffice:

```
df<-data.frame(c(sample(2:100,1000,replace=TRUE)),c(sample(2:100,1000,replace=TRUE)))
sample<-list()
div<-seq(100,nrow(df),100)
for(i in 1:length(div))
{
    sample[[i]]<-df[(100*(i-1)):div[i],]
}
```

Comment: Hanjo, why does sample[2] produce the 1st 200 rows instead of rows 101-200?

Comment: @CatherineSmith, corrected the code. Also, when referring to a list item, the convention is to use double brackets `[[`. So to call your second sample dataset would be `sample[[2]]`. Hope this helps you out

Comment: The code samples 1:100, then duplicates row 100 in the next sample. Also, since a data frame might have nrow%%100!=0, this modified code worked for me, and feeds in just my needed column from the df: 
        `sample<-list()
 div<-seq(100,(nrow(df)+99),100)
 for(i in 1:length(div))
 {
     sample[[i]]<-df[(100*(i-1)+1):div[i],1]
 }
 sample<-lapply(sample, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @A Webb, using `split` should help.

```
df<-data.frame(c(sample(2:100,1000,replace=TRUE)),
               c(sample(2:100,1000,replace=TRUE)))

# For sequential grouping
groups<-10 
split(df, factor(sort(rank(row.names(df))%%groups)))

# For Random sampling of 100
split(df, sample(1:groups, nrow(df), replace=T))

sapply(groups_split, yourfunc)
```

more efficient ways probably exists, hope to see new answers.